Lighthouse detecting multiple LCPs
In the react website that I built, I have multiple images that keep shuffling in the hero section in a nice animation, as you can see. The problem is that lighthouse, and many other performance metric sites that I used, all detect each image to be an LCP on it's own, which makes the performance terrible. You can see in this picture that each time an new image appears (when the 3s interval between the animations ends), a new LCP is detected 
And this is the GTmetrix report. You can see that it's detecting the LCP to appear at 7.5s, after the having the first image loaded & have shown the animations of the 2 previous images.

What can I do to let it know that the LCP I'm concerned about is the first image only?
I tried to load the first image, show it, then fire the animation cycle of the 3 imagesonly after having the 3 images loaded, but that didn't work.

You issue is that all three images are the exact same size. In this case the LCP algorithm also takes pixel density into account to decide on which image is the "most contentful".
And your images are, in order shown:

65.5 KB
71.3 KB
107 KB

When I use a local override to reverse the order they are displayed at, the LCP does not change.
So you either need to have a higher quality image as the first image shown, or lower quality images as the second and third images shown.

Thanks! I tried using a higher quality image as the first one and it was detected as the only LCP element. It's interesting to see that this is the solution, since I now have to trade off some of the performance by having the heavier image (as I can't lower the quality of the other images more than that).
Again, I appreciate your help!

Yeah it's a bit of an odd case to be honest, and not one that that bit of the LCP check was intended for. you could try other solutions that make them ineligible (e.g. having the 2nd and 3rd images off screen completely, or initially drawn with opacity: 0 - both of which would make them ineligible as LCP candidates. But that might also be a little flakey. LCP is a heuristic and, while it works well for most sites, there will always be edge cases like this one where it doesn't.
